# -- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95 when install cmake-3.10.3

Tags: cmake, fortran

when I installed the cmake-3.10.3,I was stuck,it seems that I need a fortran compiler.I don't know the reason.The following is what happened when I run "./configure" in  cmake-3.10.3 folder.
...

```
-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBMD
-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBMD -- not found
-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBMD
-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBMD -- not found
-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBMD
-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBMD -- not found

-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  

-- Looking for cbreak in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
-- Looking for cbreak in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so - found
-- Looking for elf.h
-- Looking for elf.h - found
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95
^C
```

...
not run down this place

Comment: cmake is checking if you have it, it doesn't need it, but if you have it it, it needs to know where it is.

Comment: But Idid failed to install it。It means that I need modify the configure file if I don't need fortran compiler ?Thanks for answering

Comment: did it? You didn't post any error messages.

Comment: Yes，no error message occured，the installation has been waiting in this place for at least 10 minutes，I can't wait such a long time，some mistakes must have happened。

Comment: What about the log file? What does it contain?

Comment: try ./configure --verbose     it is probably doing something. Could take over an hour to complete.

Comment: Maybe it is not the fortran compiler that stuck the installation process，I uninstall gfortran and try it again。the same mistake took place again. 
I used my colleague's computer，All things OK！So I will check the next command(After the "finding compiler") to find the reason. thanks!